# RAM and MEMORY usage in VM

Tags: python, vmware

I'm building a dashboard to monitor the VM performance and resource usage using pyvim package. The properties I would like to monitor are free disk space(VM and not the HOST) and free RAM (VM and not the HOST) available. To be more specific I would like to obtain metrics similar to 'free -m' and 'df -h' bash commands. And these metrics are monitored and once RAM usage is high I will trigger a clear cache procedure to free the RAM. I tried using [python-vmstats](https://github.com/lgeeklee/python-vmstats/blob/master/py-vminfo.py) but it obtains the host related metrics rather than what I'm looking for. Help me if I can make use of [python-vmstats](https://github.com/lgeeklee/python-vmstats/blob/master/py-vminfo.py) in this case.